# Can jQuery UI’s highlight effect be applied to a form text input?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Wondering if jQuery UI’s ‘highlight’ effect can be used on a form text input. I would like to animate the background colour to indicate a field was successfully updated (individual field, animation triggered by Ajax success event).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Jquery animate function. First change the background color of text box using animate to green to notify user something has been saved successfully then you can ease it out to the original color again. You can write this code in your ajax success function.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>highlight demo</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <style>
  #toggle {
    background: #fff;
  }
  </style>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 
<p>Click anywhere to toggle the box.</p>
<input id="input-animate">
 
<script>
$( document ).click(function() {
  $( "#input-animate" ).animate({
          backgroundColor: "#009900",
          easing: "easein"
        }, 1500 , function(){
          $( "#input-animate" ).animate({
          backgroundColor: "#fff",
        }, 500)
        })
});
</script>
 
</body>
</html>
```